# R - How to normalize the values in matrix using R

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this.

```
term        SaS   PaP   WH
affection   3.06  2.76  2.3
jealous     2     1.85  2.04
gossip     1.3    0     1.78
wuthering   0     0     2.58
```

I want to convert this into a normalized matrix as below

```
term        SaS     PaP     WH
affection   0.789   0.832   0.524
jealous     0.515   0.555   0.465
gossip      0.335   0       0.405
wuthering   0       0       0.588
```

I tried to normalize the values using  scale and sweep. But I am getting the below mentioned error

sweep(terms, 2, colSums(terms), FUN ="/" )
Error in colSums(terms) :
  *'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions*

> scale(terms, center = FALSE, scale = colSums(terms))
>   Error in colSums(terms) :
>     *'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions*

**This is the class type**

```
> class(terms)   
[1] "DocumentTermMatrix"       "simple_triplet_matrix"
```

Kindly help.

**Update**

As per the below suggestion from @small_data, i have changed the code as follows:

```
  terms <-DocumentTermMatrix(obama.train.p,control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE)))
inspect(terms[1:2, 1:100])
sweep(terms, 2, colSums(as.matrix(terms)), FUN ="/" )
scale(terms, center = FALSE, scale = colSums(as.matrix(terms)))
```

Luckily it has not thrown any error. But it has not normalized the data.

```
Docs           93republican94 93son 93stopgap 93surge94 93the 93we 93where 93whi 93you a10  abandon abbottabad
  Obama 1.txt               0     0         0         0     0    0       0     0     0   0 2.321928          0
  Obama 10.txt              0     0         0         0     0    0       0     0     0   0 0.000000
```

If you could see for the word abandoned, even before and after normalization the value is 2.321928. Any help on this will be useful for me.

Thank you

Comment: @small_data88 - Thank you. this has not thrown any error. But it is not normalized the data. Posted an update to the question. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @small_data88 - I was thinking that to be a dataframe. However the class of "terms" shows to be a simple_triplet_matrix. I never heard about it.

Comment: @small_data88 - ok, do you think something else should be done in order to normalize the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of first column's class is factor `sweep` function does not works. Try this:

```
data.frame(term=term$term,sweep(term[,-1], 2, colSums(term[,-1]), FUN ="/" ))


       term       SaS       PaP        WH
1 affection 0.4811321 0.5986985 0.2643678
2   jealous 0.3144654 0.4013015 0.2344828
3    gossip 0.2044025 0.0000000 0.2045977
4 wuthering 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2965517
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am getting a different error now. Error in colSums(terms[,-1]): 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions. Any idea on this?

Comment: Should this be an array in order to apply colSums function?

Comment: @Arun Maybe you need to change `term` class into `data.frame` using `as.data.frame`. Try it before my answer `term<-as.data.frame(term)` then run my answer. colSums works with matrix like objects. An array of at least two dimension means it should have columns and rows like matrix.